# slideToggle wont push down a div below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

**First, here's the link to JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/chani987/uu693a0v/**

Upon a click on `choice 1` or `choice 2` link, .hiddenbox div pops out.

The slideToggle javascript is working fine. The problem is that I was expecting the footer div to be pushed down when .hiddenbox div is toggled, but the footer stays where it was and .hiddenbox div overlaps with the footer.

I've tried changing `position: absolute` to `position: none;` for .hiddenBox, but it would cause the div to position on the top of the page instead.
Is there a way to make the footer div to slide down as a hiddenBox pops while the hiddenBox comes right after the previous divs?

It's my first time posting on stackoverflow. If I haven't provided needed or enough resources, please let me know! Thanks

Comment: if you want the `footer` to slide down the hidden `div` should be positioned `relative` not `absolute` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/8p0bhx82/)

Comment: Your code is different, try setting position relative on the code the OP supplied and you will see it doesn't work.....

Comment: I've tried changing .hiddendiv to be positioned relative, it's not working.. Have you changed anything else in your fiddle link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, there is probably a better way though. Add

```
Position:relative;top:0px;
```

To your #main_footer css.

```js
$('#audience_text').click(function(){
$("#artist_type").slideUp('slow');
$("#audience_type").slideToggle('slow');
var a =$("#main_footer").css("top");    
a=="0px"?$("#main_footer").css("top","+=200"):$("#main_footer").css("top","0");
                                   
 });
$('#artist_text').click(function(){
$("#audience_type").slideUp('slow');
$("#artist_type").slideToggle('slow');   
 var a =$("#main_footer").css("top");    
a=="0px"?$("#main_footer").css("top","+=200"):$("#main_footer").css("top","0");

});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uu693a0v/2/)

Comment: Sorry Yun, You need to put position:relative;top:0px; in the css for the main footer. Updated answer and added JSfiddle